# Google Adwords - how to specify AND and OR in Keyword

Tags: google-ads

There are many ways to define keywords for a campaign. However is there a way to make ORs?

While searching in google it would like '"keyword (ketwordOr1|keywordOr2)"'.
That would return results such as "keyword keywordOr1" OR "keyword keywordOr2" but not keyword alone.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that. The only variant of the traditional broad match, "phrase" match and [exact] match keyword bid types is usage of the [broad match modifier](http://www.google.co.uk/ads/innovations/bmm.html) which you may want to look into.

Why can't you just use:-

```
"keyword keywordOr1"
"keyword keywordOr2"
[keyword keywordOr1]
[keyword keywordOr2]
```

Surely that achieves what you're trying to?

Comment: Not sure, started with adwords yesterday :( currently reading docs. and was wondering if its possible

Comment: I see, as I've listed, that is the proper way to include what keywords you wish your ad to be triggered for and this is where you list all possible/worthwhile variants (which result in the same as AND/OR's etc).